# How to open div on center screen position?

Tags: javascript, css

How to open div on center screen position ?

Comment: Are you asking how to center a div vertically and horizontally?  Like this?  http://www.infinitywebdesign.com/research/cssverticalcentereddiv.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a size for the DIV and position it absolutely (or Fixed), like this:

```
div{
     position:absolute; /* can also be 'fixed' */
     top:50%; left:50%; 
     width:200px; height:100px; 
     margin:-100px 0 0 -50px;
     z-index:99;
}
```

Or if you don't want to place it absolutly positioned, you can give it a **width**, and set it to:

```
div{ margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: but that is a CSS or Javascript question? if the width and height are unknown, than it's a JS question, and then you need to measure the size of the div, and set the CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

This only works if the div has a width of 95% or less

Comment: If you want it to open like a window check out plugins such as http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/